# How can you tell a device has rotated so you can reload a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift3, frameworks, uicollectionview

I want to `invalidateLayout()` of the custom UICollectionView when the bounds are changed. I know that I can call this method from the controller using `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`. But since I want to make this custom UICollectionView as a framework, I want to implement the function **without** being dependent to the controller.

If I try to `invalidateLayout()` inside `override open func layoutSubviews()` then I get an infinite loop.

What is the best way to implement what I want with the constraints give?

Comment: you mean when you rotate device you want to update layout?

Comment: @TusharSharma you are a mind reader !!

Answer (score 0):

View Controllers have this method -:

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it is the UICollectionView that has this method? Can you give me the link to the Apple Developer Documentation? I couldn't find it

Comment: @Ham Dong Kyun its a view controller method sorry for mistake . You can just type it out and you will get one.

Comment: Sorry, but I explicitly explained that I do not want to link it to the controller.

Comment: @HamDongKyun what you meant by link to controller? Please explain .

Comment: I want the code to be in the UICollectionView subclass and not linked to any UIViewControllers.

Comment: @Ham Dong Kyun I am not getting what are you trying to achieve with that, but this is the only good way you can determine rotation and update layout without any burden.

Comment: I want to make a UI Framework as explained in the question above. Within this framework I would like to provide a collection view that will resize the cell size when the device is rotated. Due to the above request, I can not link to any UIViewController to detect the rotation.